# find_all() not finding any results when using Beautiful Soup + Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-requests

I'm experimenting with using BeautifulSoup and Requests for the first time, and am trying to learn by scraping some information from a news site. The aim of the project is to just be able to read news highlights from terminal, so I need to effectively scrape and parse article titles and article body text.

I am still at the stage of getting the titles, but I simply am not storing any data when I try to use the find_all() function. Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import strftime
import requests

date = strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

url = "http://www.thedailybeast.com/cheat-sheets/" + date + "/cheat-sheet.html"

result = requests.get(url)
c = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "lxml")

titles = soup.find_all('h1 class="title multiline"')

print titles
```

Any thoughts? If anyone also has any advice / tips to improve what I currently have or the approach I'm taking, I'm always looking to get better so please do tell!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting everything here in quotes:

```
titles = soup.find_all('h1 class="title multiline"')
```

which makes `BeautifulSoup` search for `h1 class="title multiline"` elements.

Instead, use:

```
titles = soup.find_all("h1", class_="title multiline")
```

Or, with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
titles = soup.select("h1.title.multiline")
```

---

Actually, because of the dynamic nature of the page, to get all of the titles, you have to approach it differently:

```
import json

results = json.loads(soup.find('div', {'data-pageraillist': True})['data-pageraillist'])
for result in results:
    print result["title"]
```

Prints:

```
Hillary Email ‘Born Classified’
North Korean Internet Goes Down
Kid-Porn Cops Go to Gene Simmons’s Home
Baylor Player Convicted of Rape After Coverup
U.S. Calls In Aussie Wildfire Experts
Markets’ 2015 Gains Wiped Out
Black Lives Matters Unveils Platform
Sheriff Won’t Push Jenner Crash Charge 
Tear Gas Used on Migrants Near Macedonia
Franzen Considered Adopting Iraqi Orphan
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, this makes sense. But I now notice that this only finds one of the elements, even though when I check out the url I can see there are multiple ones. Any thoughts?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - I seem to get this error when I use the json segment of your code. `ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 128661 (char 128660)` --- on another note, should I always look to json if the page is dynamic like this site?

Comment: @ploo interesting, the code worked for me as is. Well, not necessarily - it's just that here the rest of the articles are constructed with javascript, and they initially are located in the `data-pageraillist` attribute value of a particular `div` tag on the page. Here we basically read that attribute, load the value into the python list and get the `title` key for every item in the list.

Comment: Hmm I'll look into it - it's a separate issue from the question anyways. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, but `find_all` only searches the tags, it's not like a generic search function.

Hence if you want to filter by tag and attribute like class, then do this:

```
soup.find_all('h1', {'class' : 'multiline'})
```